# Display node mysql results using express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to display multiple rows using node mysql, I am stuck on getting the results into the route.

Looking at my code below, I can console all the results outside of the route, but it will only console 1 result within the route.

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'blablabla.com',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

/// start query
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3');
query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .on('result', function(row) {

        console.log(row); /// displays all 3 results

        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.send(row); /// displays only 1 result
            console.log(row); /// displays only 1 result
        });
    });


/// end query
connection.end();
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

**EDIT**

After a lot of research, I stumbled upon this https://youtu.be/g-_l_v_uX6E?t=15m36s which demonstrated what I was trying to achieve which was multiple results into the route.

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'blablabla.com',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'database'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

var units = null;

connection.query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3', function(err, rows, fields){
      if(err) throw err;
      units = rows;

      connection.end();
      app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send(units); /// multiple results to the browser
      });
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understund you question correct you want to get your database information when you call `http://127.0.0.1...`?

If so you need to make some small modifications to your code:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'blablabla.com',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
});


function getRows(res){
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

        /// start query
        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3');
        query
            .on('error', function(err) {
                connection.end(); /// end query
                console.log(err);
            })
            .on('result', function(row) {

                res.send(row); /// displays only 1 result
                console.log(row); /// displays only 1 result
                connection.end(); /// end query
                console.log(row); /// displays all 3 results
                return;
            });
   });

}


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            getRows(res);

});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response, everything within the app.get route is undefined? and the code throws a `events.js:16 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event` error, which disappears if I comment out `connection.end();`

Comment: If you comment out `connection.end()` is rows still `undefined`?

Comment: Yes unfortunately, sorry:)

Comment: Updated my solution, try it out! :)

Comment: I am so sorry, `node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:78  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors` followed by `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`  and still displaying one result when I place `res.send(row);` after `connection.end();` I commented out the previous `res.send(row);` before `connection.end();`

Comment: Do your `app.get` function look like mine? `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` often happens when you try to do `res.send` multiple times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123169/discussion-between-jason-and-joakim-ericsson).